# Microsoft teams channel deletion event listener

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is their any event apart from bots to listen to channel deletion in teams.
So that I can perform some actions on channel deletion.
Currently I could see only bots can handle such events.

Answer (score 0):

Bots are one way, but this should also be possible using the Graph - specifically there is a Change Notification capability, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-team-and-channel . Per this doc:

> You can get notified whenever a team or channel is created, updated, or **deleted**.

Comment: thank you,
this is what i was looking for,  i have a personal tab in teams , i have to make changes in the ui for the tab, once the channel has been deleted, how to achieve it in react js?

Comment: That's a much much bigger question than your original one, especially to ask here in the comments section. Let's close this out (Mark it as Answer) and ask a separate question about that so others can see it properly. Be sure to mention what you've tried, and what your overall scenario is

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - can we achieve the change notifications in react js

Comment: @chetanSharma is it possible